# EXTJS Grid view refresh after inserting to the database

Tags: extjs

I have a grid and form, I successfully insert it to my database field, but my problem is that, the data I entered is on the grid , but the data come from the database are not displaying, I need to refresh(f5) before the data will display.

Are they any function that will retrieve automatically the data from database after clicking a button?

Thanks in advance, Any ideas will help. :D

Comment: can you post the response from the server?

Comment: If submitting the form changes data on the server database, the grid cannot know about it. You must call `grid.getStore().reload()` to refresh the grid's store.

Comment: I try this one, but still , the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you try grid.getView().refresh()

Comment: yes I try it. But still it doesn't get the data from my database. And One more is that, data are been inserted twice